Fourier transform of 2D Hilbert transform
I would like to rigorously evaluate the Fourier Transform of the 2D analogue of the symbol of the Hilbert transform $s:\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C$ with
$$ s(x) = \frac{(x_1+ix_2)^m}{\vert x \vert^m}.$$
The Fourier Transform of this function exists in the sense of tempered distributions. But how can I find it rigorously?
Since someone asked me about my attempts: Formally the computation is not too bad:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
 &=\int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{im\theta} e^{i\rho \sin\theta} \rho \ d\rho \ d\theta\\
    &=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{im \theta}(-\sin^{-2}\theta+i\pi\delta'(\sin\theta))\,d\theta\\
    &=\int_0^{2\pi} -im e^{im\theta}(\cot(\theta)+i\pi\delta(\sin\theta)) \,d\theta\\
    & = 2\pi m,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $m$ is a positive integer.
However this is not a rigorous computation but quite formal.

@SineoftheTime I added my attempt

Is $m$ supposed to be a natural number?

@Pelota Yes a positive integer!
